# Detsructuruing Dynamic Objects values based on property names in es6

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring, ecmascript-2016

```
let filter: Product = {
  name: 'nokia',
  price: 20,
  createdDate: '12-12-2019'
}
```

Here I destructuring the code based on a filter.

The filter has events, that expose a data in below format:

I have a table and the table contains filters. In filters, there have an event.filters are exposing the data based on which filter we selected.if I choose the name it will give below.

```
"filters":{"name ":{"value":"sss","matchMode":"equals"}}
if i choose price  it will given below .

"filters":{"price ":{"value":"20","matchMode":"equals"}}
```

Here I have destructured the data based on properties.

```
  let {name,price,createdDate}= event.filters;

       console.log(name,'name'); // here name  i will get {"value":"20","matchMode":"equals"}

       console.log(price,'price'); // it is undefined.
```

once I get the filtered name value, I need to map to the Product Interface property value

I need to map the value based on selected values and the remaining property to be empty. how can I do it in destructuring?

I can able to do it in switch case and check the name and map the value, is there any way to do in es6 destructuring object

Solution I have found:

Incoming dynamic objects

```
let x=  event.filters; // "filters":{"name ":{"value":"sss","matchMode":"equals"}}
```

// predefined initial values

```
let filter: Product = {
  name: 'nokia',
  price: 20,
  createdDate: '12-12-2019'
}


// predefinded objects
       for (let property in   filter) {  

        for(let m in x){
inner objects
          if(m === property)
          {
            console.log(`1Object key= ${property}  and 2ObjectValues= ${x[m].value}` );


          // assigned incoming values to matched object property
            filter[property]= x[m].value;


          }

        }
      // console.log(`key= ${property} value = ${filter[property]}`);
     };
```

Comment: It looks like you should use a simple loop over the properties, not any destructuring.

Comment: @Bergi I have looped two objects if objects key mapped i have assigned the incoming value to the matched property. it works ...i have updated the solution in StackOverflow. can you review, is it possible to provide better solution.appreciated your feedback

Comment: No need to use two loops. You need one loop over the property names, then you can access that property by name on any object

Comment: @bergi  still in confusion I need to compare the two objects property if incoming value name, i need to find out the incoming value is name,then should assign the income value to the first object property name , remaining values should be default values.

Answer (score 1):

```
filters = event.filters;
const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => {
  for (const field of Object.keys(filters)) {
    const filter = filters[field];
    const val = product[field];
    switch (filter.matchMode) {
      case 'equals':
        if (val !== filter.value) return false;
        break;
      case 'greater':
        if (val <= filter.value) return false;
        break;
      case 'less':
        if (val >= filter.value) return false;
        break;
      // etc...
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: I guess you meant either `for (const field in filters)` or `for (const field of Object.keys(filters))`.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is better to re-struct the filter data from:

```
"filters":{"name ":{"value":"sss","matchMode":"equals"}}
```

to somethins like:

```
"filters":[{"field": "name/price/etc", "value":"sss", "matchMode":"equals"}, ...]
```

so you can filter products like:

```
filters = event.filters;
const filteredProducts = products.filter(product => {
  for (let i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
    const filter = filters[i];
    const val = product[filter.field];
    switch (filter.matchMode) {
      case 'equals':
        if (val !== filter.value) return false;
        break;
      case 'greater':
        if (val <= filter.value) return false;
        break;
      case 'less':
        if (val >= filter.value) return false;
        break;
      // etc...
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

Comment: or you can not re-struct filters, but traverse object instead of array...
anyway, I think it is not a question of destruction, it is better to make it more universal with traversing all filters and compare all with product's data... so filter can be complex and can be extended later

Comment: @aleksandered I have 24 property in grid so I don't want to use switch condition. for eg) i have provided 3 properties in StackOverflow.No I don't have an option it is a third party grid ngrPrime use provided like that in filtering event. whatever column we filter  it  just provided that fieldname and value in above specified format.

Comment: the switch is not for props, but is for compare types... number of props is unlimited and not affects the number of cases in the switch...

Comment: without re-structing the filter, you just replace for to like this:
for (const field in Object.keys(filter)) ....

Comment: added example for your struct:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61639258/3499604